# R Studio Probability Lower Tail

Tags: r, distribution

Can somebody tell me why these two are equivalent?

```
qnorm(.1, 55, 6, lower.tail = FALSE)
qnorm(.9, 55, 6, lower.tail = TRUE)
```

In my head, I'm thinking for the first one, it grabs everything to the right of the 10%. For the second, it grabs everything to the left of the 90%.

How are these equivalent?

Comment: They are complementary cases, and probability always adds up to 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `qnorm` function tell you what values are associated with which provided quantile of the normal distribution. Your logic is correct. The reason that they are the same is that the amount of area under the normal distribution to the left of `62.68931` is `90%`, while `10%` is to the right of `62.68931`.

You can see this more clearly if you plot it.

```
library(ggplot2)
qplot(seq(30,80, by = .1), 
             dnorm(seq(30,80, by = .1),
                   mean = 55, sd = 6),
             xlab = "support", ylab = "density", 
  geom = "line") + 
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = qnorm(.1, 55, 6, lower.tail = FALSE)))
```

[image]